# Does mate framework for flex leak with injectors?

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, mate

I have been trying to pinpoint a memory leak I have in my flex application and I have just discovered that it might be related to mate.

I'm using mate's Injectors (in a mapping file) to inject an item to a popup:

```
<Injectors target="{MyTitleWindow}">
    <PropertyInjector targetKey="item" source="{MyManager}" sourceKey="item" />
</Injectors>
```

I'm then using `PopUpManager.addPopup` and `PopUpManager.removePopup` to show/remove the popup but when I profile my application, I see that the count of `MyTitleWindow` objects only incline (removePopup does not free up the memory)

When I remove the injectors, everything works well ...

Has anyone encountered that issue? I guess I can override this issue by not using the injectors but I do hope there's a simpler solution ...

**Edit**

I've just learned that starting from version 0.8.8, PropertyInjector includes a property called softBinding which should (as I understand) fix this issue, but it doesn't ...

Comment: Have you tried using the Flash Builder Profiler?

Comment: I have tried using the FB profiler. That's how I know objects are not being GC'd